# Only one Google Apps script event firing

Tags: google-apps-script

The Google Apps script below only fires some events. For example, if I change column 16 to X, it updates column 17 correctly. But if I then delete the X in column 16, it deletes the date in column 17, but does not reset the fontcolor (`dataRangeAll.setFontColor(false)` in `colorRow(r)`). The fontcolor reset works if it's by itself though.

Is is something with running two events after each other, or is the code below wrong in some way?

An example spreadsheet [can be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvmCHAibmHeNdGdWakVURXprdnFidWd5SjQwbHRYNUE).

```
function setDate(r){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, 17);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];


  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);

  var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0100','yyyy-MM-dd')


  if(row[2] != ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(r,12).setValue(Sdate);
  } else if(row[2] == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(r,12).setValue("");
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

}

function setDate2(r){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, 17);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];


  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);

  var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0100','yyyy-MM-dd')


  if(row[15] != ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(r,17).setValue(Sdate);
  } else if(row[15] == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(r,17).setValue("");
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

}


function colorRow(r){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 12, 1, 6);
  var dataRangeAll = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, 17);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];

  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);
  var sheetDate = new Date(row[0]);

  var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0100','yyyy-MM-dd')
  var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0100', 'yyyy-MM-dd')

  dataRangeAll.setFontLine(false);

  //Om faktura har skickats
  if(row[4] != ""){ 
    dataRangeAll.setFontLine("line-through");
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
    dataRangeAll.setFontColor('#cccccc');

  //Om faktura inte har skickats och fakturadatum har uppnåtts  
  }else if(row[0] != "" && Sdate >= SsheetDate && row[4] == ""){ 
      dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 170, 86);
      dataRange.setFontColor('#000000');
      dataRangeAll.setFontColor(false);

  //Om faktura inte har skickats, men fakturadatum är tomt  
  }else if(row[0] == ""){ 
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
    dataRange.setFontColor('#cccccc');
    dataRangeAll.setFontColor(false);

  //Om faktura inte har skickats, men fakturadatum inte har uppnåtts
  }else{ 
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
    dataRange.setFontColor('#777777');
    dataRangeAll.setFontColor(false);
  }




  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
}


function onEdit(event)
{
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  if (r >= 3) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

    //När en produktion markeras som klar eller inte
    var watchColumn = 3;   //A=1, B=2, C=3...  
    var activeColumn = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();

    if (activeColumn == watchColumn){  //only run if change in watch column 
      setDate(r);
    }

    //När en faktura markeras som skickad eller inte
    var watchColumn2 = 16;   //A=1, B=2, C=3... 
    var activeColumn2 = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();

    if (activeColumn2 == watchColumn2){  //only run if change in watch column 
      setDate2(r);
    }

    colorRow(r);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see it working in the sample you provided. To confirm, i added an X in column C and I saw column L fill in with a date and turn gold. Then I removed the X and the date went away and the color was removed. Correct?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's working correct. But try removing an x in column P. The text should revert back to black. It does sometimes, but then add the x and remove it again and now the text does not revert to black.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried column P as well and while it was a bit slow sometimes overall it caught up. So I think the gist of this is that *this is supposed to work* and perhaps something slow causes a race condition? Can you try to simplify the code to make it run faster?

Comment: Thanks. Will see if I can manage to simplify it. I'm quite new to programming in Google Apps Script/Javascript.

Comment: The example spreadsheet seems to be working as described. Since the problem was originally posted, the Sheets service has been updated. Should this question be closed?

Comment: Yes, @Mogsdad, it can be closed. Thanks!